# Fixed menu on scroll with unknown height of previous elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm searching for a way to fix a menu on top when user scroll past certain height.

The thing is I can't just use `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 70){` because the height of the elements before the menu is variable.

The page layout is something like:

```
* Banner <-- This is a variable height banner
* Menu
* Content
```

I could read on `domready` the menu's `y` position but I also need to take into account browser resizing as the banner height could be changed by some media queries.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: so why not read the banner height and use that value in your tests ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your script

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".menu").offset().top > 100) {
        $(".menu").addClass("scrolling-nav-header");
    }
    else {
        $(".menu").removeClass("scrolling-nav-header")
    }
});
```

and your css will have the functionality for this class="scrolling-nav-header" you want. something like this:

```
menu.scrolling-nav-header{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't get to the part when I tell that I don't know ahead of time the height of the elements before the menu...

Answer (score 0):

Set the absolute offset top of the scrollable header to the container (window) scroll value when this is greater than the relative header offset. Would be something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var scrollheader = $('.scrollheader'), scrollcontainer = $(window);
  var scrolling, shY;
  (function updateOffsetTop() {
    if (!scrolling) {shY = scrollheader.offset().top;}
    scrolling = false;
    setTimeout(updateOffsetTop, 5000); // Define lapse to update the height above.
  })();
  scrollcontainer.scroll(function() {
    var wsY = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wsY > shY) {
      scrollheader.offset({top: wsY});
    } else {
      scrollheader.css({top: 0});
    }
    scrolling = true;
  });
  scrollcontainer.trigger('scroll');
});
```

```css
.scrollheader {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Stuff before<br/>More stuff before<br/>Stuff before<br/>More stuff before<br/>
Stuff before<br/>More stuff before<br/>Stuff before<br/>More stuff before<br/>
<div class="scrollheader">Scroll Header</div>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>Stuff after<br/>More stuff after<br/>
```

Note: Updated to check periodically changes of the content height above the header.